# multi input file upload php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to upload the photo and then fill out the form.
I need to put six input to upload photos how can I change the code?
and if I want to put the photo form in the middle of the text form how do you do it?

this is to add information to mysql

```
<?php
include("../Connections/connect.php");
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['aggiungi'])) {
    $foto1          = $_GET['foto1'];
    $titolo         = $_POST['titolo'];
    $sottotitolo    = $_POST['sottotitolo'];
    $testo1         = $_POST['testo1'];
    $testo2         = $_POST['testo2'];
    $sottocategoria = $_POST['sottocategoria'];

    $inserisci = "INSERT INTO soluzioni (foto1, titolo, sottotitolo, testo1, testo2, sottocategoria) VALUES ('$foto1', '$titolo', '$sottotitolo', '$testo1', '$testo2', '$sottocategoria')";
    $res = mysqli_query($connessione, $inserisci) or die(mysqli_error($connessione));
    if ($res) {
        header("Location:index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Errore";
    }
}
?>
```

This is the form

```
<div>
   <form action="../upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self">
      <div>
         <input type="file" name="foto1[]" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile1(event)">
         <input type="submit" value="CARICA IMMAGINE" />
      </div>
   </form>
   <form method="post" target="_self">
      <input type="submit" name="aggiungi" value="AGGIUNGI" />
   </form>
   <?php echo $error; ?>
</div>
```

and this is the upload file

```
<?php
!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'][0], 'images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
$estensione = strtolower(substr('images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0], -4));
$dimensione = 1000;
$width      = $dimensione;
$height     = $dimensione;
//  JPG
if ($estensione == ".jpg" || $estensione == "jpeg") {
    list($width1, $height1, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
    $ratio_orig = $width1 / $height1;
    if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
    }
    $ridotta1 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $source1  = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
    imagecopyresized($ridotta1, $source1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width1, $height1);
    imagejpeg($ridotta1, 'images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0], 75);
}
//  PNG
if ($estensione == ".png") {
    list($width1, $height1, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
    $ratio_orig = $width1 / $height1;
    if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
    }
    $ridotta1 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $source1  = imagecreatefrompng('images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
    imagecopyresized($ridotta1, $source1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width1, $height1);
    imagepng($ridotta1, 'images/' . $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0]);
}
// name and path
$nome_foto = $_FILES['foto1']['name'][0];
header("Location: Admin/aggiungi.php?foto1=$nome_foto");
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have *!* at the start of the line ```move_uploaded_file(```? In that same line, note the ```[0]```, that's the index to the uploaded file. The 2nd would be ```[1]```, etc. Add the input type='file' for each additional file to upload.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You have to loop through $_FILES['foto1'] to upload each file selected.

Comment: As suggested in the below answer, you have to put multiple attribute to your file input to upload multiple files.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes I have recently learned to write php and many things at school do not explain it in depth yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You add attribute **multiple="multiple"** to input.

Comment: yes I know the attribute multiple but I need six separate inputs connected each one with a name in the db (photo1, photo2, ect ..) so that if I want to insert only photo 2 and photo 6 I can insert ignoring the 1, 3, 4, 5 and in the db only the photo2 and photo6 fields are filled